# Calendar API Quota limits and policy on increasing quotas

Tags: ios, api, calendar, quota

I am planning on developing an iOS app that uses the Google Calendar API.  Currently the dashboard shows that my App can use 200,000 Calendar requests per day.  It looks like this could be exceeded by 20,000 people using the App sending just 10 requests per day.  If the App is successful we could easily exceed that limit...

What is the policy for allocating my App a higher quota if/when I need it?  Are quota increases always granted for serious users/products?  Is there a pricing option that allows for unlimited requests?  Or some other way to get guaranteed higher quota...??

I'd like to understand this before spending the time to build the App and distribute.  If the App is successful I'd like to have some clarity of how, and under what circumstances, increased Quotas would be granted.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The Google Calendar API has a courtesy limit of 10,000 queries per day. You can send a request from the "Quotas" pane of the Google APIs Console.

- https://code.google.com/apis/console/#%3aquotas

If you are providing a free service then Google may increase your Quota.

Comment: Hi Vish, thanks for the comments.  Does this mean that that if I have a paid application that Google will *not* increase quota?  BTW, the link you included doesn't work for me...  Thanks.  Mike

Comment: Not necessarily. Have you contacted Google ? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing